# grep between two list

Tags: bash, grep

I have two files on my Linux machine. The first "list.txt" contains a list of objects (2649 objects) while the second "list_interactors.txt" contains a shorter list with some of the objects in the previously list (719 objects) and for each of these there are in other columns some variables associated. I would like to obain a list of all the objects (2649) with the associated variable for the specific objects in file "list_interactors".

Example:

file `list.txt`

```
6tyr_A_002__________
7yer_2_009__________
3erf_1_001__________
2dr5_D_2-3__________
```

file `list_interactors.txt`

```
6tyr_A_002__________    6tyr1_B    QRT54R   AAAAA
3erf_1_001__________    3erf2_B    QAEF6R   XXXXX
```

`output.txt`

```
6tyr_A_002__________    6tyr1_B    QRT54R   AAAAA
7yer_2_009__________
3erf_1_001__________    3erf2_B    QAEF6R   XXXXX
2dr5_D_2-3__________
```

I'm not very pratical of the programming languages. I try to use the function grep with this script:

```
grep -f list.txt list_interactors.txt
```

but the output is a file like the file "list_interactors.txt".

Could you help me please?

Comment: Probably the tool you are looking for is `join`, not `grep`. Check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join)

Comment: The behavior of `grep` you see is because the `-f` option takes _matching rules_ (=filtering rules) from the file. In the end, your command says "print all lines in `list_interactors.txt` that contain one of the strings in `list.txt` (which in your case is _every_ line in `list_interactors.txt`).

Answer (score 12):

```
$ join -a 1  <( sort list.txt ) <( sort list_interactors.txt )
2dr5_D_2-3__________
3erf_1_001__________ 3erf2_B QAEF6R XXXXX
6tyr_A_002__________ 6tyr1_B QRT54R AAAAA
7yer_2_009__________
```

This uses `join` to do a relational JOIN operation between the two files.  The first field will be used as the join key by default.

The `-a 1` option makes `join` output all lines in the first file, even if there is no match in the second file (it does a "left join").

The input data to `join` needs to be sorted, and we do this by calling `sort` on each file individually in two process substitutions on the command line.  You could also opt for pre-sorting the files.

If your data is tab-delimited, you may want to add `-t $'\t'` to the start of the `join` command's arguments.  This would make the output retain the existing tab delimiters.

Redirect the output by adding `>output.txt` to the end of the command if you want to store it in a file.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the sorting you can use `awk`:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR {s[$1]=$0}
    FNR!=NR {if(s[$1]) print s[$1]; else print $0}
' list_interactors.txt list.txt
```

Output:

```
6tyr_A_002__________    6tyr1_B    QRT54R   AAAAA
7yer_2_009__________
3erf_1_001__________    3erf2_B    QAEF6R   XXXXX
2dr5_D_2-3__________
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} {print ($1 in a ? a[$1] : $0)}' list_interactors.txt list.txt
6tyr_A_002__________    6tyr1_B    QRT54R   AAAAA
7yer_2_009__________
3erf_1_001__________    3erf2_B    QAEF6R   XXXXX
2dr5_D_2-3__________
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl one liner can also do :

```
$ perl -ane ' { chomp;$s{$F[0]}=$_; } END { print "$s{$_}\n" for sort(keys(%s))  }' list.txt list_interactors.txt 
2dr5_D_2-3__________
3erf_1_001__________    3erf2_B    QAEF6R   XXXXX
6tyr_A_002__________    6tyr1_B    QRT54R   AAAAA
7yer_2_009__________
```